# UINavigationControllerDelegate willShow method is not called

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently creating an app that uses UINavigationController for screen transitions.

The problem I encountered was the print string in the willShow delegate method on screen B will not be displayed. The transition from screen A to B to A willShow delegate method will be called correctly and even though it is displayed in the console, the transition from screen A to B to C to B to A will cause the method to it will not be called and will not be displayed.

ViewController.swift

```
// First view
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Home"
    }
}
```

SecondViewController.swift

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.delegate = self
        navigationItem.title = "Second"
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if let _ = viewController as? SecondViewController {
            print("=====(open)willShow::SecondViewController=====")
        } else {
            print("=====(close)willShow::SecondViewController=====")
        }
    }
}
```

ThirdViewController.swift

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.delegate = self
        navigationItem.title = "Third"
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if let _ = viewController as? ThirdViewController {
            print("=====(open)willShow::ThirdViewController=====")
        } else {
            print("=====(close)willShow::ThirdViewController=====")
        }
    }
}
```

Logs of the transition from screen A to B to A

```
=====(open)willShow::SecondViewController=====
=====(close)willShow::SecondViewController=====
```

Logs of the transition from screen A to B to C to B to A

```
=====(open)willShow::SecondViewController=====
=====(open)willShow::ThirdViewController=====
=====(close)willShow::ThirdViewController=====
```

Logically, you should see this message  at the end.

```
=====(close)willShow::SecondViewController=====
```

[FirstViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54U7O.png)

[SecondViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMzFn.png)

[ThirdViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxbFb.png)

Comment: You are reassigning navigationController's delegate in Third view controller. `viewDidLoad` is being called in the middle of transition (because View Controller content is loaded lazily, right when it needed), making the output so cryptic. You have to assign `navigationController?.delegate` once, and is better to be on upper level.

Comment: Thank you so much.
The willShow method of the second view controller is now called when the third view controller does not assign to the delegate of the navigationController.
However, the willShow method of the Thrid view controller is not called anymore. What should I do?

Comment: As far as I see, overriding `viewWillAppear(_:)`/`viewDidAppear(_:)` and `viewWillDisappear(_:)`/`viewDidDisappear(_:)` in second and third view controllers is better option for your task. No need to play with delegates at all.